# Get latest from last available value SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables as

**Master**

```
MasterID PaperID Version PaperName
1        ISBN-1X 1       Medical Research
2        ISBN-1X 2       Medical Research(2)
3        ISBN-1X 3       Medical Research(2.1)
4        ISBN-2X 1       Some Research(1.0)
5        ISBN-3X 1       Unpublished Research(0.0)
```

**PaperAuthor**

```
MasterId AuthorName
1        ABC
2        XYZ
4        LMN
```

**Note:** Author table only gets entry if its not same author as previous version. Otherwise paper version gets updated in master, author remains same.

How do I get latest version of paper with last updating author

**Expected Result**

```
MasterID PaperID Version PaperName                  AuthorName
3        ISBN-1X 3       Medical Research(2.1)      XYZ
4        ISBN-2X 1       Some Research(1.0)         LMN
5        ISBN-3X 1       Unpublished Research(0.0)
```

My attempt(s):

```
Select M.MasterID, M.PaperID ,M.Version, M.PaperName, A.AuthorName
From Master M 
Inner Join 
(select  PaperID , max(version) maxversion from Master group by PaperID ) M1 
on m1.PaperID  = M.PaperID   AND M1.maxversion = M.Version
left join PaperAuthor A on M.MasterID  = A.MasterID
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=45cf063914dfce5588d9549f5be99270)

Comment: MasterId as 3 is wrong, I think, as it does not have corresponding PaperAuthor

Comment: @VenkataramanR OP wants `latest version of paper with last updating author`.

Comment: @zealous, oh ok. fine. got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single `join` and some window functions:

```
select top (1) with ties m.masterid, paperid, version, papername,
       max(authorname) over (partition by paperid, grp) as authorname
from (select m.*, pa.authorname,
             count(pa.authorname) over (partition by m.paperid order by m.version) as grp
      from master m left join
           paperauthor pa
           on pa.masterid = m.masterid
     ) m
order by row_number() over (partition by m.paperid order by m.version desc);
```

This uses the `with ties` trick to get the most recent version without an additional subquery.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b5927dd80cc8a1db59465ede5e332b38) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following with `row_number`, here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1a4a3cd8d7182eed52aa0f87135867c5).

```
;with mst as
(
  select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by PaperID order by version desc) as rnk
  from master
),
ppauth as
(
  select 
    *,
    row_number() over (order by MasterID desc) as rnk
  from PaperAuthor
)


select
  m.MasterID,
  PaperID,
  Version,
  PaperName,
  AuthorName
from mst m
join ppauth p
on m.rnk = p.rnk
where m.rnk = 1
```

Output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| MasterID  PaperID  Version     PaperName        AuthorName|
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  3        ISBN-1X    3    Medical Research(2.1)    XYZ    | 
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OP wants `latest version of paper with last updating author`, so I have corrected my answer.

Comment: I added two lines to demo and now it takes last author for all papers   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=45cf063914dfce5588d9549f5be99270

Comment: @Cannon you should be very clear what you ask. without having proper test data no one can provide you exact result.

Comment: Just added link to the demo

Comment: @Cannon, i think there is some problem with data. Why masterId 3 does not have any paper author. But, MasterId 4 is having author.  You should define table with primary keys and foreign keys properly, so that there is no ambiguity

Comment: @Cannon, how is ISBN ISBN-1X is having author as LMN ? you are mapping with last author entry in PaperAuthor. is that correct ?

Comment: That's the issue I am highlighting with zealous suggested solution. Its taking last author for all ISBNs. ISBN-1X should return XYZ, ISBN-2X should have LMN

Comment: @Cannon there is no way you can do without having common column to join. there is a problem with your data.

Comment: Agree. But that's the way it is with tons of records. Can't change data.

Comment: @Cannon, I have added one more answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query. It maps the recent author with the latest book data for each ISBN.

```sql
;WITH CTE_Master AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PaperID ORDER BY Version DESC) AS recentOrder
FROM Master
)
SELECT c.MasterId, c.PaperId, c.Version, c.PaperName, pa.AuthorName
FROM CTE_Master as c
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT TOP 1 MasterId, AuthorName From PaperAuthor WHERE MasterId <= c.MasterId ORDER BY MasterId Desc) as pa(MasterId,AuthorName)
WHERE c.recentOrder = 1
```

```
+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------+------------+
| MasterId | PaperId | Version |       PaperName       | AuthorName |
+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------+------------+
|        3 | ISBN-1X |       3 | Medical Research(2.1) | XYZ        |
|        4 | ISBN-2X |       1 | Medical Research(2.1) | LMN        |
+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------+------------+
```

**UPDATE: If you want NULL Authors also**

```sql
;WITH CTE_Master AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PaperID ORDER BY Version DESC) AS recentOrder
FROM Master
)
SELECT c.MasterId, c.PaperId, c.Version, c.PaperName, pa.AuthorName
FROM CTE_Master as c
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT TOP 1 MasterId, AuthorName From PaperAuthor WHERE MasterId <= c.MasterId ORDER BY MasterId Desc) as pa(MasterId,AuthorName)
WHERE c.recentOrder = 1 and c.MasterId <= (SELECT MAX(MasterId) FROM PaperAuthor)
UNION ALL
SELECT c.MasterId, c.PaperId, c.Version, c.PaperName, NULL as AuthorName
FROM CTE_Master as c
WHERE c.MasterId > (SELECT MAX(MasterId) FROM PaperAuthor)
```

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------------------------+------------+
| asterId | PaperId | Version |         PaperName         | AuthorName |
+---------+---------+---------+---------------------------+------------+
|       3 | ISBN-1X |       3 | Medical Research(2.1)     | XYZ        |
|       4 | ISBN-2X |       1 | Medical Research(2.1)     | LMN        |
|       5 | ISBN-3X |       1 | Unpublished Research(0.0) | null       |
+---------+---------+---------+---------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: MasterID 3 is ISBN-1X, last updated author is XYZ for that. So 3 should have XYZ, 4 with LMN

Comment: @Cannon, you told that we have to map with last author data. We did not have data for MasterId 3. So, how can we map XYZ for that ?

Comment: Last author for PaperId. Note section in details

Comment: @Cannon, Got it. I have updated my answer. I have also tested the same in dbfiddle link of yours.

Comment: This worked. I uncovered another scenario where there is no author and should have empty. My apologies for not having that as initial post. I see MasterId <= c.MasterId causes no author row to pick last author.

Comment: @Cannon, there are some problem with the data. I have updated my answer. My suggestion is to first fix the data issues and then write queries. Otherwise, we will keep getting corner cases and have to fix it through code and it can cause issues also.

Comment: Your solution works for 5 sample rows, but not on generic table with this scenario. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=09d43ce9f2befa8905b3ed35ca4e34ca Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Cannon, as data is having gaps in masterid, it is difficult to write generic query. there are data issues. I would suggest you to fix them first. may be post separate question of how to fix data issues with UPDATE statement