# With Ties Return all rows with max of one column Sql Sever

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables as

**Master**

```
MasterID PaperID Version PaperName
1        ISBN-1X 1       Medical Research
2        ISBN-1X 2       Medical Research(2)
3        ISBN-1X 3       Medical Research(2.1)
4        ISBN-2X 1       Some Research(1.0)
5        ISBN-3X 1       Unpublished Research(0.0)
```

**PaperAuthor**

```
MasterId AuthorName
1        ABC
2        XYZ
4        LMN
```

**Note:** Author table only gets entry if its not same author as previous version. Otherwise paper version gets updated in master, author remains same.

How do I get **all** versions of paper with last updating author as author for all versions

**Expected Result**

```
MasterID PaperID Version PaperName                  AuthorName
1        ISBN-1X 1       Medical Research           XYZ
2        ISBN-1X 2       Medical Research(2)        XYZ
3        ISBN-1X 3       Medical Research(2.1)      XYZ
4        ISBN-2X 1       Some Research(1.0)         LMN
5        ISBN-3X 1       Unpublished Research(0.0)
```

Solution from other post:

```
select top (1) with ties m.masterid, paperid, version, papername,
       max(authorname) over (partition by paperid, grp) as authorname
from (select m.*, pa.authorname,
             count(pa.authorname) over (partition by m.paperid order by m.version) as grp
      from master m left join
           paperauthor pa
           on pa.masterid = m.masterid
     ) m
order by row_number() over (partition by m.paperid order by m.version desc);
```

Note: This is similar to [Other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056910/get-latest-from-last-available-value-sql/62064878#62064878) with different expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions;

```
 select mpa.*,
       max(case when mpa.version = max_author_version then authorname end) over
           (partition by paperid) as the_author
from (
select m.*,pa.authorname,
             max(case when pa.authorname is not null then version end) 
             over (partition by m.paperid) as max_author_version
      from master m left join
           paperauthor pa
           on pa.masterid = m.masterid
     ) mpa;
```

The inner subquery gets the latest version with a valid author name.  The outer query shmeers it over all the records.

[DB Fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0fdf9a77fa3915ee73f69a7bfde1d37e)